# Get Sleep data from Google Fit and Apple Healthkit in Flutter

Tags: flutter, sleep, healthkit, google-fit

I am making a sleep analysis application using Flutter and I found this library called Health to get sleep data from both Gooole Fit and Apple Healthkit https://pub.dev/packages/health/versions/2.0.5

Unfortunately, for some reason the data doesn't include the time user go to bed, when they wake up, or total sleep time, which I need to do analysis on.

Is there a way to get these variables for each sleep cycle. Currently the data looks like this, just a bunch of sleep segments one after the other. [Sleep raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1OfJ.jpg)